# SVN на Windows 7

Tags: svn, windows

Посоветуйте SVN, которую лучше всего поставить на Win7 (64bit). TortoiseSVN, как я понимаю, на Win7 не идет?

Comment: TortoiseSVN на win7 идет

Comment: да, спасибо, уже вижу

Comment: комменты кончились, отвечу тут.

`c:/windows/system32/drivers/etc/hosts` использоуйте far, проводник не покажет эту директорию.

последняя ссылка была на google =) с запросом `svn servers`, там много всего вылезет.

Comment: да всё, с хостом уже разобралась)

Comment: подскажите. пожалуйста, почему при попытке апдейта файла выдается ошибка http://static.diary.ru/userdir/2/0/0/4/2004853/76699209.png , хотя TortoiseSVN — Release lock выдает http://static.diary.ru/userdir/2/0/0/4/2004853/76699210.png ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Идет, у меня стоит она и работает на w7-64. Есть еще subversion -- Collab Subversion Client, к примеру.

там [есть 64бит](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tortoisesvn/files/1.7.10/Application/TortoiseSVN-1.7.10.23359-x64-svn-1.7.7.msi/download?accel_key=61%3A1352883695%3Ahttp%253A//tortoisesvn.net/downloads.html%3A58a5c5a9%2469e4cc65a2a72594051e5de64d01d795887af92f&click_id=e4b6474a-2e39-11e2-9998-0200ac1d1d8a-1&source=accel), не качайте 32бит версию для 64битной ОС, когда есть нативная версия для системы. ;)

Comment: Скачиваю TortoiseSVN-1.7.10.23359-win32-svn-1.7.7.msi, запускаю установку - http://static.diary.ru/userdir/2/0/0/4/2004853/76698472.png

Comment: дык пакет битый, написано же. если бы оно было не совместимо, то так и написало бы.

Comment: а вообще там [есть 64бит](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tortoisesvn/files/1.7.10/Application/TortoiseSVN-1.7.10.23359-x64-svn-1.7.7.msi/download?accel_key=61%3A1352883695%3Ahttp%253A//tortoisesvn.net/downloads.html%3A58a5c5a9%2469e4cc65a2a72594051e5de64d01d795887af92f&click_id=e4b6474a-2e39-11e2-9998-0200ac1d1d8a-1&source=accel)

Comment: такая же ошибка выскакивала и при установке TortoiseSVN-1.7.10.23359-x64-svn-1.7.7, но видимо пакет тоже был поврежден. после повторной закачки все установилось. подскажите, я правильно понимаю, что TortoiseSVN работает только в ие?

Comment: ? оно в проводник какбэ встраивается... причем тут ие? это клиент же.

Comment: первый раз с svn работаю, еще ничего не знаю, сейчас как раз читаю инструкцию для новичков

Comment: вот [хороший сайт](http://svnhowto.com/)

в по поводу сервера для всего этого -- [Collab Subversion Client](http://www.collab.net/downloads/subversion) либо лучше [так](https://www.google.ru/search?q=svn+servers&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&channel=fflb)

Comment: последняя ссылка битая. я пока здесь читаю http://www.easycoding.org/2010/02/27/rabota-s-tortoisesvn.html
подскажите, если мне нужно в hosts ещё прописать: 209.160.54.55   svn.lh-broker.com, где это прописывается ?